# Error handling in angular using try catch with pipe and map

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, observable, try-catch

How can I return an error and send it to the component ts so that the users can detect whats the error? Codes below is a login function.

I want an error message coming from the API to return at component ts and display it as angular material toast.

```
signIn(payload: signInRequestPayload): Observable<Account> {

try {
  return this.query({
    document: login_user
    payload,
  }).pipe(
    map((result: any) => {

      console.log(result);
      if (result.data.length) {
        return result.data[0] as Account;
         }
        throw Error("")
    })
  );
} catch (error) {
  throw Error(`Unable to retrieve user account`);
}
```

}

Comment: Delete try catch. This might help: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError

Comment: I'm getting an error 'Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Account>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.' when I replaced the try catch to catchError

Comment: Can you show your updated code?

Comment: I just removed the try catch and then start with the return through subscribe (with catchError format)

Answer (score 0):

We can throw an error inside of the `map` and the `subscriber` can handle the error.

```
signIn(payload: signInRequestPayload): Observable<Account> {
  return this.query({
    document: login_user,
    payload,
  }).pipe(
     map((result: any) => {
       if (result.data.length) {
         return result.data[0] as Account;
       } else {
         throw new Error('...');
       }
     });
  );
}
```

Then it should be up to the subscriber to handle the error:

The first callback function is for success and the second callback is for the error scenario.

```
signIn.subscribe(response => {/* successful response */}, error => {/* error response */});
```

Comment: where can I add the subscribe?

Comment: Who is calling the `signIn` method? I assume they are subscribing to it.